# jQuery groupwise "Select All" checkbox

Tags: jquery

I need your help to resolve one of my issue. I have a Product list with me with Checkboxes.

Requirement is that if the checkbox of the group head is selected then all the checkboxes inside that should be selected. If after that someone deselect one, then it should removed from the grouphead checkbox.

Here is my code

```
<ul id="productFilter">
<li><input id="pr3" type="checkbox" /><h3>List1</h3>
<ul class="secLevel">
<li><input id="pr3" type="checkbox" /><h3>Product 1</h3>
<ul class="secLevel">
<li><input id="107A-10" type="checkbox" /><label for="107A-10">107A-10</label></li>
<li><input id="107A-11" type="checkbox" /><label for="107A-11">107A-11</label></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><input id="pr3" type="checkbox" /><h3>Product 2</h3>
<ul class="secLevel">
<li><input id="BFPT" type="checkbox" /><label for="BFPT">BFPT</label></li>
<li><input id="DEV831" type="checkbox" /><label for="DEV831">DEV831</label></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><input id="pr3" type="checkbox" /><h3>List2</h3>
<ul class="secLevel">
<li><input id="pr3" type="checkbox" /><h3>Product 3</h3>
<ul class="secLevel">
<li><input id="020" type="checkbox" /><label for="020">020</label></li>
<li><input id="025" type="checkbox" /><label for="025">025</label></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><input id="pr3" type="checkbox" /><h3>Product 4</h3>
<ul class="secLevel">
<li><input id="1A2" type="checkbox" /><label for="1A2">1A2</label></li>
<li><input id="1A4" type="checkbox" /><label for="1A4">1A4</label></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>    
</ul>
```

Comment: you could start by giving the inputs different ids, you should never have the same id for more than one product on a page.

Comment: Off topic: Are you aware that you can wrap `<input>` elements with `<label>` to avoid the ID-based mapping? `<input id="107A-10" type="checkbox" /><label for="107A-10">107A-10</label>` -> `<label><input type="checkbox" />107A-10</label>` (provided that the `ID` is not used elsewhere.)

Comment: Yes, I have changes the Ids. Now what to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Give value attribute to each outer checkbox

```
if ($('pr3').attr('checked')) {
 //find the checked value
//based on the value check inner checkboxes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the structure of your HTML (you can change this and make sure you change the jquery selectors accordingly)  .

```
 <ul class="secLevel">
    <li><input id="pr1" type="checkbox" class='mainfilter' /><h3>Product 1</h3>
    <ul class="secLevel" id="pr1Items" >
      <li><input id="107A-10" type="checkbox" /><label for="107A-10">107A-10</label></li>
      <li><input id="107A-11" type="checkbox" /><label for="107A-11">107A-11</label></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>


 <ul class="secLevel">
    <li><input id="pr2" type="checkbox" class='mainfilter' /><h3>Product 1</h3>
    <ul class="secLevel" id="pr1Items" >
      <li><input id="someId1" type="checkbox" /><label for="someId1">107A-10</label></li>
      <li><input id="someId2" type="checkbox" /><label for="someId2">107A-11</label></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
```

jquery

```
$('.mainfilter').change(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $(this).parent().next('ul').children().attr('checked','checked');
  }else{
     $(this).parent().next('ul').children().removeAttr('checked');
  }

});
```

For top level check box

```
<input id="parentChkId" type="checkbox"  />



$('#parentChkId').change(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
     $('#parentChkId input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
  }else{
    $('#parentChkId input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
  }
```

});

Comment: Jayanth, I have change your code to work for me and its working fine now. Thanks, But I have three level hirarchy. If you can see my HTML there is a parent chk box is there. Please help me

Comment: then just change the selecter  level use $('#parentChkId input:checkbox') instead of $(this).parent().next('ul').children()

Comment: Not able to get it. can you please give me the exact code, if you  dont mind